# Why do stock or commodity prices sometimes rise suddenly just before market close?

Tags: markets

I often (not always but often) see that stock/commodity price rise sharply when market is approaching close. Shouldn't this be opposite (taking intraday profit)?
What is the purpose of this strategy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is often the case where traders are closing out short positions they don't want to hold overnight, for a variety of reasons that matter to them.  Most frequently, this is from day traders or high-frequency traders settling their accounts before the markets close.